# Difference between SKIP locked and nowait

Tags: sql, oracle

Difference between cursor with SKIP locked and nowait in pl/sql?

Comment: Oracle uses PL/SQL, I believe.  But the tags should say as much.

Answer (score 23):

I think this image I found is the best example to describe the difference

[image: Example]

[Detailed Explanation](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/oracle-skip-locked/)

Comment: Can you add where you found it, preferably with a link to the original, or at least show attribution?

Comment: @AlexPoole:Updated the link

Comment: @GauravSoni That links back to a page you wrote, but where did the original come from?

Comment: @jonearles:No sir,it was from some other blog , will provide you the link , i was searching but dint find the link ,so provide the link of mine .