# How to create a Select for Update error in mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, locking

I have read about `Select for Update`, also reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758710/minimal-example-of-using-select-for-update-to-isolate-rows) question and wanted to lock rows in my local database make sure my queries work.

I have tried:

```
select * from User where id=10 for update; 
>for update 1 row(s) returned   0.063 sec / 0.000 sec

select * from User where id=10 for update;
>for update 1 row(s) returned   0.063 sec / 0.000 sec
```

I expected to get an error  on the second select for update statement.

How can I lock a row for update on my local?

Comment: did you use two separate sessions?

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin No. I just opened the MySql Workbench, connected to the DB and executed those statements.

Comment: create another connection to DB and execute second statement on it

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin I got the same response. Created 2 separate connections, ran one statement opened the other connection and ran the other. I got the same answer

Comment: maybe autocommit is enabled. Try execute `start transaction;` before executing select statements in each session. And check `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` in `my.cnf`

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin yep, that was the issue. Thanks :)